# how can I connect to gitlab project of groups from shell

Tags: gitlab

I want to pull a commit from a gitlab project of group (notice: I am a member of the group) I don't know how to connect to the repository from my gitlab a count. I install the git in my ubuntu, configure then add the ssh pb key to gitlab. I spend hours to know how to pull a commit but I don't get the idea. any help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the clone ssh link by clicking on the blue “clone” button in Gitlab:
[image]

Make sure to copy the link under the label of “Clone with SSH”.

In a bash terminal you would execute the following based on what you copied:
`git clone <your-gitlab-user-name>@gitlab.com:name-of-group/project-name`

Next you would checkout the branch/commit that you are interested in:

1. `cd project-name`
2. `git fetch origin`
3. `git checkout <branch-name>`

Depending on your ssh setup on your Ubuntu machine, you may need to add your private key to your ssh-agent before running the `git clone` command.
In case you run into issues related to this, try the following commands:

1. `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`
2. `ssh-add /path/to/private/key` # Normally in `~/.ssh/` dir
3. `git clone <your-gitlab-user-name>@gitlab.com:name-of-group/project-name`

Comment: No problem. I was just working setting up something very similar with Gitlab. Gitlab rocks!